# Why doesn't the div extend out to element padding?

Tags: html, css

I've held onto this question for quite some time now; why does the padding of an element go beyond the boundaries of a `div` even with `box-sizing: border-box;`? This happens even when the `div` doesn't have a specified `height`, but a `height: inherit;` or `height: 100%;` property. It's a bit hard to explain, so please see the example beneath.

[Click here for the example.](https://jsfiddle.net/tkefhuzj/4/)

As you can see in the example above, even with the `container` having `height: 100%;`, it somehow doesn't stretch entirely out to the very bottom edge of the button. Why is this happening, and is it possible to make it stretch to the very edge of an element with padding?

I hope this was understandable, I couldn't find any other words to explain the issue through. If there are any quarrels or confusion, please let me know! I will try to help and clear them up to be the best of my ability.

Comment: The button is an inline element. It behaves like text. If you change the button's display type to `inline-block` or `block` it will not extend beyond the container. https://jsfiddle.net/v5ffpnoq/

Comment: I see, so basically, the parent will ignore paddings whenever the child is displayed as an inline element? Why is this though? Shouldn't the padding of a text element be a part of the element itself?

Comment: Not just the parent. The vertical padding values don't affect the flow of the inline elements so siblings will also "ignore" the padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As many users have commented, the solution to this matter is to add `display: inline-block;` or `display: block;` to the `inline` element. All credit to those who have helped. Thank you. Closing this matter now.